# Scan a file folder in android for file paths

Tags: java, android

So i have a folder at "mnt/sdcard/folder" and its filled with image files. I want to be able to scan the folder and for each of the files that is in the folder put each file path in an arraylist. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use

```
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
File directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder");

File[] files = directory.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    paths.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

See [`listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) variants in `File` (one empty, one `FileFilter` and one `FilenameFilter`).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use the `java.io.File` API with [FileFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html).

```
File dir = new File(path);
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getAbsolutePath().matches(".*\\.png");
    }
};
File[] images = dir.listFiles(filter);
```

I was quite surprised when I saw this technique, as it's quite easy to use and makes for readable code.