# How to create the gallery folder in android programmatically?

Tags: android, gallery, photo-gallery, whatsapp, file-manager

[image]

[image]

Note: I need to create Gallery App like this. ie. first show sdcard folders thumbnail images first, then, when I click thumbnail, then, need to show another new page to show subimages.
like whatzup image upload, and Gallery App from play store..

Please help me anybody to come out from this.
when i search from google, only examples available like normal singles images showing gallery-view examples only.

Comment: maybe https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D/+/master

Comment: thank you nizammoidu..after run this example, when i touch the screen and scroll it, that time pointerIndex out of range error will coming..

Comment: its little hard to clear the error.. if possible can u suggest some other gallery view source code..thanks nizammoidu...

Comment: i think you have show folder of gallery and show all images.
check this project for that
https://github.com/DivyangMetalia/AndroidGallery

Comment: You can find something useful here https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version

Comment: Please Refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693077/1332892

Comment: @harikrishnan Did you find the solution can you please refer any link for this, i have google it whole day but i didnt get correct way

Comment: hi, android gallery app link is given below by some answers.. just check this..

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1.Outer activity which display folders:

Create an activity with grid view of custom item.Each item is framelayout with image and   semi-transparent background textview.

2.Second activity which display images:

Create an activity with gridview of images.

To learn how to create gridview,use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Scan folders that you want to include using a method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279404/scan-a-file-folder-in-android-for-file-paths)

Generate a thumbnail by opening an image from the folder and resizing like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420802/resize-image-from-file).

Place these thumbnails in a gridview, possibly with a small overlay stating the [name of the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242951/android-text-over-image).

When a user clicks into the folder simply generate thumbnails the same way as above but for every image.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this code - [CM Gallery](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery)

It's the official CyanogenMod gallery's source code. This will help you a lot in understanding how does gallery work.

Also go through this tutorial which I found really useful - [Android Gallery](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-displaying-images-with-an-enhanced-gallery--mobile-11130)